# Bashscript: Trying to remove some ansi and some other text bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script

Node.js code outputs to terminal and logs to file as well

I need to remove everything between '[Progress]' and this emoji '' while writing to file but should print in terminal.

Works fine on mac if i open with an vscode or similar editor but on an ubuntu machine on vim it hows everything as if nothing changed all Progress and color codes are still there.

for the emoji I tried with an code this emoji I am using is `\ud83d`

here is my code

```sh
LOG_FILE='output.log'
node inddex.js 2>&1 \
    | tee /dev/tty \
    | sed -e $'s,\[Progress\].*,,g' -e $'s,\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g' \
    > $LOG_FILE
```

My node output is something like (for multiple single line)

```
[2K[1G[Progress]: Processing Records ...[2K[1G[Progress]: Processed Records: [33m816[0m [2K[1G[Progress]: Processed Records: [33m1725[0m [2K[1G[Progress]: Processed Records: [33m2774[0m [2K[1G[Progress]: Processed Records: [33m4041[0m [2K[1G[Progress]: Processed Records: [33m5207[0m [2K[1G[Progress]: Processed Records: [33m6557[0m [2K[1G[Progress]: Processed Records: [33m8590[0m [2K[1G[Progress]: Processed Records: [33m9811[0m [2K[1G  Time taken to process [33m10000[0m records = [36m8.54 sec[0m
```

for above line I only need to process this to output file and display everything on terminal

```
  Time taken to process 10000 records = 8.54 sec
```

Comment: Using `$''` is strange with `sed`. `sed` can itself interpret hex sequences.

Comment: @KamilCuk No, not universally; that depends entirely on the `sed` dialect.

Comment: @joyBlanks try substituting `` for `\xf0\x9f\x9a\x80` hexadecimal characters.

Comment: It seems in Ubuntu it simply ignores `sed -e $'s,\[Progress.*\xf0\x9f\x9a\x80,\xf0\x9f\x9a\x80,g' -e $'s,\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g' \`

Comment: I tried #!/bin/bash and #!/bin/sh with sh script.sh and ./script.sh same thing. In mac it runs fine in Ubuntu the file has everything not removes my progress lines

Comment: ok one more thing i tried cat output.log and I didn't see the progress lines. the ansi colors were there since cat outputs to the terminal but how come Progress lines are missing there? I much dont care about ansi color codes but I need to get rid of the progress lines